# Django 1.6: Two dropdown menus in one single form not working

Tags: python, django, forms, drop-down-menu

I've two dropdown menus in one single template. They both are using the same form. But for some reason only one of the form works and gives me `MultiValueDictKeyError`in the views. It gives me error on the line `request.session["genderselect"] = request.POST['genderselect']`

So I've commented out the lines to see what happens and the code works and shows the first dropdown (name = selection). But the second dropdown of (name = genderselect) doesn't work, although they both are part of the same form.

views.py

```
def doclistings(request):
    d = getVariables(request)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DropdownSelectionForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            print form.errors
            selection = form.cleaned_data['selection']
            # genderselect = form.cleaned_data['genderselect']
            # request.session["genderselect"] = request.POST['genderselect']
            request.session["selection"] = request.POST['selection']

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/doclistings')
    else:
        form = DropdownSelectionForm()

    # d['genderselect'] = genderselect
    s_name = request.session.get('selection')  
    d['userselection'] = s_name  
    spec = Specialization.objects.get(name=s_name) 
    doctors = Doctor.objects.filter(specialization = spec).order_by('-likes')  
    d['doctors'] = doctors

    d.update({'form': form})
    return render_to_response('meddy1/doclistings.html',d)
```

forms.py

```
class DropdownSelectionForm(forms.Form):
    selection = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MY_CHOICES, widget = forms.Select, required = False)
    genderselect = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, widget= forms.Select, required = False)
```

here is the template where I've the two dropdown

```
    <select class="form-control" id="selection" name="selection">
      <option><b>Find a Doctor...</b></option>
      {% for value, text in form.selection.field.choices %}
        <option value="{{ value }}">{{ text }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>

      <select class="form-control" id="genderdropdown" name="genderdropdown">
      <option><b>Select a Gender</b></option>
      {% for value, text in form.genderselect.field.choices %}
        <option value="{{ value }}">{{ text }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>

    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  name="submit" id="ss-submit">Search</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  {% csrf_token %}

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `name="genderdropdown"` attribute to match the form field name.

In other words, replace `name="genderdropdown"` with `name="genderselect"`.